# Flutter print out from supabase

Tags: flutter, supabase-database

I have two tables in Supabase that I want to display in flutter app. One is the header and the other should be the user's choice.
But I don't understand how to print out the second table.
Something easy is surely needed.
Grateful for help
The example below gives me the raw code of questioChoices, but I only want the words.[image]

```
    //List of question from database
  List? questList;
  Future<void> question() async {
    final response = await supabase
        .from('questionHeader')
        .select('''
        header, questionChoices (choices)
        ''')
        .order('id', ascending: true)
        .execute();

    setState(() {
      questList = response.data.toList();
    });
    print(questList);
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const MyAppBar(
        title: 'Upptäck',
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            fullName != null ?
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 15, right: 10),
                child: questList != null ?
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: questList?.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Wrap(
                            children: [
                              Text((questList![index] ['header']).toString()),
                              Text((questList![index] ['questionChoices']).toString())
                            ],
                          );
                      }
                    )

                    : Text('No connection to database'),
              )

            :
            const Center(
              child: Text('No data'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

}

Comment: try to create model class, or you need to read the map

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the structure of the `questionChoices` that you are displaying, it's a `List` of `Map`.

```dart
Wrap(
  children: [
    Text(questList![index]['header']),
    ...(questList![index]['questionChoices'] as List)
        .map((item) => Text(item['choice']))
        .toList()
  ],
),
```